# Java While Loop - Calculate and Display Earnings

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, computation

I find loop statements really hard so I need help. This program lets the user input each salesperson's gross sale, calculates their commission which is $200 plus 9% of their sale, and displays the salesperson's earning. Also, to sum up all of the total sales inputted, the user should input -1, hence ending the program. This program uses a while loop and the output should be like this:

```
 ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END): 5000.00
 SALARY:  $ 650.00
 
 ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END): 6000.00     
 SALARY:  $ 740.00
 
 ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END): 7000.00     
 SALARY:  $ 830.00
 
 ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END): -1
 
 THE TOTAL SALARY FOR THE WEEK:  $2200.00   
 GOOD DAY!  THANK YOU FOR USING THE SYSTEM!
```

and so far here's the code I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        double sales = 0, salary = 0, totalSalary;
            
        while (sales >= 1) 
        {
            System.out.print("ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
            sales = scan.nextDouble();
            
            salary = (sales + 200)* 0.09;
            System.out.println("SALARY: $ " +salary);
        }
            
    }

}
```

I'm really stuck on where should I put the "while" and how would I stop the loop with "-1"

Comment: Do not use floating point types for monetary amounts!

Comment: @Fildor may i ask why

Comment: you condition would be better with `sales > 0`

Comment: That's why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/982149

Comment: @Fildor noted. thanks for this

Comment: You're welcome. It's a common one. There are even some assignment questions using floating point for money and those have been assigned by uni professors ... *smh

Comment: If you initialize `sales` with 0 and then check it to be > 1 in the loop condition, the loop will never start.  Just change the condition `while (sales >= 0)` and don't forget to add up the totalSalary in the loop

Comment: @AlexRudenko That would allow for `sales = -0.5`, though.

Comment: In fact, you actually could do with an unconditional loop. Since you need to fetch the input inside the loop, you have to validate input there, too. So you can simply `break;` if input == -1.

Comment: Also, watch, what you actually want to loop. You need to sum up sales (loop and sum until -1, **exclude -1 from sum**), then calculate `f(totalSales) = 200 + ( totalSales * 0.9 )`

Comment: And just a pro tip for clean code: avoid "magic numbers" like "200" and "0.9". Make them class fields or constants that have useful names.

Comment: while (true) + if condition

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never enter into the loop because of `sales=0`. To go inside the loop use do while loop or initialise with some other value which is >= 1.

Go and read some more about loops :

1. For loop
2. while loop
3. do-while loop

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/

Can use the following code reference

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double sales = 0, salary = 0, totalSalary;
        System.out.print("ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
        sales = scan.nextDouble();
        while (sales >= 1) {
            salary = (sales + 200) * 0.09;
            System.out.println("SALARY: $ " + salary);

            System.out.print("ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
            sales = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. salary is calculated _totally_ wrong  2. No need to use `do-while` loop and then use `if` inside it with the same condition

Answer (score 1):

As I see you must check if input=-1 then end calculation and put result.
Also user may input incorrect non numerical value and you must catch it and maybe it needs to add additional checking for negative input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sales , salary, totalSalary = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
            sales = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
            if (sales == -1) break;
            salary = 200 + sales * 0.09;               
            System.out.println("SALARY: $ " + salary);
            totalSalary += salary;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("THE TOTAL SALARY FOR THE WEEK:  $" + totalSalary + "\n" +
            " GOOD DAY!  THANK YOU FOR USING THE SYSTEM!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an infinity loop until the input set to -1.

Also, Your calc is wrong, you should use (x * 0.09) +200.

Take a look here

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double salary = 0, totalSalary = 0;
    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("ENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
            salary = scan.nextDouble();
            
            if (salary == -1)
                break;
            
            salary = (salary* 0.09) + 200;  
            totalSalary += salary;
            System.out.println("SALARY: $ " +salary);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    
    System.out.println("THE TOTAL SALARY FOR THE WEEK:  $" + totalSalary);
    System.out.println("GOOD DAY!  THANK YOU FOR USING THE SYSTEM!");
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but you are adding up error. You should sum up sales only, then calculate commission on totalSales. As is, your are adding the base salary in each iteration + rounding / floating point error.

Comment: And another thing: Do not trust user input. By accidentally typing -1000 you could mess up your calculation entirely.

Comment: @Fildor about your 1st comment, I did it based the given output that it is the correct one. About your 2nd comment, i do not trust them. But i think the main question was about the exit case.

Comment: Hmm, the requirement is a little unclear, there. The text imho differs from the example. So nevermind 1st comment, please.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, i totally agree with you

Answer (score 0):

```
int sales;
double salary = 0, totalSalary = 0;
boolean keep = true;


while (keep) 
{
    System.out.print("\nENTER SALES IN DOLLAR (-1 TO END):  ");
    sales = scan.nextInt();
    if (sales == -1)
    {
        keep = false; 
    }
    else 
    {
        salary = (sales * 0.09)+ 200;
        System.out.println("SALARY: $ " +salary);
        totalSalary = totalSalary + salary;
    }
        
}
scan.close();
System.out.println("\nTHE TOTAL SALARY FOR THE WEEK:  $ " +totalSalary);
System.out.print("GOOD DAY!  THANK YOU FOR USING THE SYSTEM!");
```